# Beginners question: Factorised expression, not sure how book got the answer

Tags: factoring

I have an expression:

$2a^3 / 3a^2 * 6a^5$

and my book gives the answer:

$4a^6$

I get where the $a^6$ is from but how is the $4$ worked out?

Comment: $\frac{2}{3}\times 6=\frac{12}{3}=4$.

Comment: Wow, that's obvious. Thanks, I don't know why that didn't even occur to me... must be having a bad day!

Comment: Please include parentheses in expressions like $a/b*c$.  Many people mean $a/(b*c)$ when they write it.  You didn't, but it makes it easier on the reader to be sure.  It is true, when you quote a book, you should quote exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It was written in the book exactly like that but with a "÷" instead of a /.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because its $2\cdot6/3 = 12/3=4$. That's without the $a$'s and its exponents.

Comment: Wow, that's obvious. Thanks, I don't know why that didn't even occur to me... must be having a bad day!

Comment: Don't worry, it happens to us all... :)

Comment: Think my brain just automatically decided "You'll end up with an ugly fraction  that you'll never turn in to 4 if I divide 2 by 3, find another way" haha. Thanks again!